# changing syntax from sqlplus format to mysql format

Tags: mysql, sqlplus

I am currently trying to change the syntax from sqlplus to mysql to set the look and feel of an report file so can be more organized

```
set pagesize 66
set linesize 75
ttitle center EarthOrientation Parameters(U) 2                                       

column year heading "Year" format 9999
column month heading "Month" format 99
column day heading "Day" format 99
column mjd heading "MJD" format 99999
select year, month , day , mjd, from     TB_PARAMETER_UI order by year,month,day,mjd; */
```

does anyone know the correct replacement for setpage size and set line size and tittle and how to set columns in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

That's in Oracle you can set that, in Mysql I haven't heard about something like that, but you can use this:

```
select LEFT(`text`,100) as columname from table1;
```

where 100 is the number of caracter, however if you want to display the result in other format you can use `\G` instead `;`

EDIT

```
mysql> select left(first_name,4) as short_name from t1 limit 10;
+------------+
| short_name |
+------------+
| PENE       |
| NICK       |
| ED         |
| JENN       |
| JOHN       |
| BETT       |
| GRAC       |
| MATT       |
| JOE        |
| CHRI       |
+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT 2:

```
mysql> select left(first_name,4) as short_name 
from t1 limit 10 into outfile 'test.txt';
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT 3:

Try this:

```
mysql -e "select left(first_name,4) as short_name 
from t1 limit 10" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.txt
```

it give a result like this:

```
short_name
PENE
NICK
ED
JENN
JOHN
BETT
GRAC
MATT
JOE
CHRI
```

Comment: but how would i set the title and column headers? i do not understand your above syntax as it would relate to mine?

Comment: remeber i am outputting to a file not the mysql client?

Comment: this works on the mysqlclient but as i have stated before i am tryign to write this output to a text file? when i use the SELECT SELECT Year as YEAR FROM TB_PARAMETER_UI INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.txt'; it DOES NOT produce a column header as it would in mysqlclient

Comment: i want columns and a title in the txt file that gets produced when i run my mysqlquery. Most of you are thinking that i want a header WITHIN mysqlclient but this is nto the case. The output is going to a txt file in my tmp directory and i want this file to have a column names for each column and also a title. This is what my sqlplus syntax is doing but i do not know how to do it in mysql ?

Comment: In your third edit how is this going to give me the column header short_name without even having that as part of your sql statement?

Comment: to me it show with the "short_name" as a header, can you edit your post and put how do you expect the result will be?